# JMeter don't execute all request of my test plan

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

This is my Test plan:

```
Test Plan
   |- Thread Group A
   |     |- Login
   |     |- HTTP request1
   |     |- HTTP request2
   |     |- ForEach Controller
   |        |- HTTP request3
   |        |- HTTP request4
   |        |- ForEach Controller 
   |           |- HTTP request5
```

When I run it, JMeter execute only Login and HTTP request1

In the view results tree :

[image]

Comment: Do you have errors in log? Did you set Duration in Thread Group?

Comment: No I did not set any duration in my thread, and both log4j2 file and jmeter.properties doesn't contain any error

Comment: Check jmeter.log for errors

Comment: There is nothing in log :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you have `Successes` box ticked in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener?

[image]

If yes, it might be the case your `HTTP Request 2` sampler fails and doesn't produce anything for the ForEach Controller.

1. Try unticking `Successes` box
2. Inspect [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) for any suspicious entries
3. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) and check .jtl results file - it should have all Sample Results included

Comment: Successes box is already unticking, I have run it in non-GUI mode but I got same result only Login and request1 are executed